# Jitsi-Meet: poor video quality and video failure

Tags: linux, networking

I use "Jitsi-Meet" as a video chat for my community.
Unfortunately, the video of some users simply drops out. And the video quality levels off at around 180p-360p, although 360p was specified as the minimum and 720p as the maximum.

The users themselves mostly have cams with 720p or 1080p, but the others only see 180p-360p. So you only see a heap of pixels

Do you understand what I mean?

- The server is connected with 20 MB/s (~160 MBit/s) (used is usually about 2-5 MB/s in DL and about 0,5-2 MB/s in UL)
- 4 CPU cores (utilisation approx. 5-20 %)
- 3 GB RAM (utilisation approx. 1-2.5 GB)
- Number of participants: 3-10

I actually mean MB = megabyte and not MBit

How else can I solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure, have you already checked this? https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/2191#issuecomment-346163550

Comment: Is the server directly issued a public IP address? Is the server doing anything else? I have a dedicated 1GB 1vCPU cheap hosted VM handles up to 4 users no problem, but doesn't do anything else and installed using the [project configuration guide](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-quickstart).

Comment: Yes, the server has an IPv4 (NAT) and an OWN IPv6 and is perfectly accessible via both.

Unfortunately, the above link did not solve my problem.

By the way, the problems occur regardless of the number of users, i.e. regardless of whether there are 2 or 8 people.